# Why does this line of script not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When data-word is called I want a sound and an image to show and play. I have tried many different ways but can't figure it out.

Here is one way...

```
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){

listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic", "data audio");

}
 console.log(listOfWords);
```

I have also tried...

```
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){

listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic");
listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio");


}
console.log(listOfWords);
```

But no such luck.

The second way does the bottom but not the top, I need both the data-audio and the data-pic when the data-word is called.

Can anyone help?

HTML...

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="wordlist">
  <li data-word="mum" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/13/00/06/head-31117_640.png"></li>
  <li data-word="cat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/03/23/13/cat-46676_640.png"></li>
  <li data-word="dog" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/02/21/14/gray-46364_640.png"></li>
  <li data-word="bug" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/16/12/17/black-35741_640.png"></li>
  <li data-word="log" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/13/11/18/fire-31929_640.png"></li>
  <li data-word="dad" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/13/00/05/old-31110_640.png"></li>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in your code. Do you want answers with jQuery?

Comment: I want to see your word-game once you finished it :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){
   listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = {
         "pic" : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
         "audio" : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
   };
}
```

Then for a given item in the `listOfWords` object you can do:

```
var currentWord = "cat"; // set current word key somehow, then:
console.log(listOfWords[currentWord].pic);
console.log(listOfWords[currentWord].audio);
```

With jQuery:

```
var listOfWords = {};
$("#wordlist li").each(function() {
    var $item = $(this);
    listOfWords[ $item.attr("data-word") ] = {
        pic : $item.attr("data-pic"),
        audio : $item.attr("data-audio")
    };
});
```

Comment: It didn't work because you didn't do what I said to retrieve the `pic` and `audio` values from within `listOfWords`, you only copied the part that put the values in. When you want the audio associated with `rndWord` you need to say `listOfWords[rndWord].audio`, and similarly the pic will be `listOfWords[rndWord].pic`. http://jsfiddle.net/bEYJH/7/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the list items and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve data attribute values.

```
var listOfWords = [];
$("#wordlist li").each(function(index, item) {
  // where liData is { word: "a", audio: "b", pic: "c" }
  var liData = $(item).data();
  listOfWords[liData.word] = liData;

  console.log("word: " + liData.word + ", audio: " + liData.audio + ", pic: " + liData.pic);
});
```